# SQL Server connecting several Selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following statement:

```
Select No, Region = 'Ohio'
FROM table
where PostCode >='0001'
AND PostCode <= '4999'
```

which updates me the table with the correct state in the field Region. How can I expand that statement with several other WHERE conditions in the same statement?

e.g.

```
Region = 'NewYork'
Where PostCode >='5000'
AND PostCode <= '7999'
```

My solution would be to build several Statements, for each Region, but there must be a better way having them all in one.

Comment: A bit unclear what you want, if you need to link postcode ranges to names you could create a table with [from, to, regionName] and JOIN it with `a.postcode between b.from and b.to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two common ways to select/set different values based on multiple criteria in a single query are `case` statements and doing a `join` on another table with those values. I should also point out that you can take advantage of the `between` operator in SQL server for much of this.

---

**CASE statements in a single query**
A case statement might be useful if you have a small set of criteria, or if you just need to throw together an adhoc query. Here is an example of using a case statement:

```
select
    No,
    Region = case
        when (PostCode >= '0001' and PostCode <= '4999')
            'Ohio'
        when (PostCode between '5000' and '7999')
            'NewYork'
        else
            'Unknown'
        end
from [...]
```

---

**JOIN a table with the values and criteria**
This is definitely the better method for something like evaluating 50 states - especially since this data is likely static. The idea is that you will want to have a table that contains the criteria and the value, and then join it to the table.

Here is an example using a temp table - you would likely want to use a real table for something as common as states.

```
-- Setup a #states table
create table #states (state varchar(20), PostCodeMin char(4), PostCodeMax char(4))
insert into #states values ('Ohio', '0001', '4999')
insert into #states values ('NewYork', '5000', '7999')

-- Now query it
select
    t.No,
    State = isnull(s.state, 'Unknown')
from
    my_table t
    left outer join #states s
        on (t.PostCode between s.PostCodeMin and s.PostCodeMax)
```

Note that in the above query, I do a left outer join to #states, in case the state isn't setup. I also select the State using `isnull`, in case the outer join doesn't return anything for that particular row in my_table.

Comment: the second JOIN statement was exactly what I was looking for and is working fine and performant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field using a case statement on region. If there is going to be many "Unknown" records returned then you may want to tweak the WHERE clause to filter out nonessential records for better performance.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    Select 
        No, 
        Region = 
            CASE 
                WHEN PostCode >'0001' AND PostCode <='4999' THEN 'Ohio'
                WHEN PostCode >'5000' AND PostCode <='7999' THEN 'New York'
            ELSE
                'Unknown'
            END
    FROM table
    where PostCode >='0001' AND PostCode <= '7999'
)AS X
ORDER BY
    Region
```

Comment: Why the need for a derived table?

Comment: It is not needed unless you want to order by the derived field.